# Delete a row from table view using custom button - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3, delegates

How to delete a row from tableview using custom buttom

```
//CustomCell.swift

protocol FavoriteCellDelegate {
    func deleteButton(sender:CustomCell)
}

class FavoriteItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    var delegate: FavoriteCellDelegate!
    @IBAction func deleteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate.deleteButton(sender: self)
}
}


CustomClass:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,CustomCellDelegate{
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
// all necessary functions for table view....

// Function delegated to perform action.
func deleteButton(sender:FavoriteItemTableViewCell){
    //How should I delete. How can I get index path here
}
```

}

**Q. What should I write in the deleteButton function ? I am unable to get the indexPath here so what should I do instead. I already have another button in cell and the delegation is working fine.**

Comment: `indexPathForCell` passing in `sender`

Comment: Do you have to use delegate on this? There are simpler ways to accomplish this requirement.

Comment: I tried using addTarget and it was giving an exception then I searched and someone on stackoverflow wrote that there is no other way but to use delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get indexPath using table view point like this

```
let buttonPosition : CGPoint = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: tableview)
let indexPath = tableview.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
```